# Wrong legends in ggplot2 with two different plot types in one graph based on the same dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please consider the following:

I want to plot a step-wise curve (using `geom_step()`) and some smooth lines (using `geom_line()`) in one graph using `ggplot2`.

I manage to create a graph but the labels are wrong and cannot be corrected using `scale_color_discrete()`.

**Desired outcome:** Based on the data (see below), line "hello" is the upper line, followed by "foo" and "bar", but the labels are not correct. In addition, I also need a label for the, now missing, `geom_step()`curve.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

---

Reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Data
db <- data.frame(time = 0:100,
                 step = 1-pexp(0:100, rate = 1),
                 foo = 1-pexp(0:100, rate = 0.4),
                 bar = 1-pexp(0:100, rate = 0.5),
                 hello = 1-pexp(0:100, rate = 0.1)
                 )

# Plotted with wrong labels (automatically)
ggplot(data = db, aes(x = time, y = step)) +
        geom_step(show.legend = T) + 
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = foo, col = "red")) +
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = bar, col = "blue")) +
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = hello, col = "green"))
```

[image]

Looking at the labels, one can already see that the description of the color and the color of the line do not match.

```r
# Still wrong labels
ggplot(data = db, aes(x = time, y = step)) +
        geom_step(show.legend = T) + 
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = foo, col = "red")) +
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = bar, col = "blue")) +
        geom_line(aes(x = time, y = hello, col = "green")) +
        scale_color_discrete(name = "Dose", labels = c("foo", "bar", "hello"))
```

[image]

Changing the labels obviously wont help.

Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I tried this too: `db %>% gather(key, value, -time)` But how can I make sure that each plot type is relying on the respective data? I guess that I would need to subset the `aes()` in some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the color you want to have inside the aesthetics-call. This means you match the color to the label "red" and not use the color "red". 
You can fix this for example like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data = db, aes(x = time, y = step)) +
  geom_step(aes(color = "step")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = foo, color = "foo")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = bar, color = "bar")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = hello, color = "hello"))

p
```

[image]

Note that I dropped the `x = time` as this is inherited from the `ggplot`-call in each step. If you want to change the color for each of the lines, you should now use for example `scale_color_manual` like the following:

```
p  +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Dose", 
                     values = c("step" = "black", "foo" = "red", 
                                "bar" = "blue", "hello" = "green"))
```

[image]

Another option would be to transform you data to the long format:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

new_db <- gather(db, type, value, -time)

ggplot(data = filter(new_db, type != "step"), aes(x = time, y = value, color = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_step(data = filter(new_db, type == "step"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Especially the middle part with the color selection is very helpful (that was what I was searching for too but didn't post here). Would you also know how I can make "step" first in the legend?

Comment: You can modify the order of your legend with adding `breaks = c("step", "foo", "bar", "hello")` to the `scale_color_manual`.